# How to add item cost in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to add work item cost but its show original value.

Example:

```
item[1].cost =2 ,item[2].cost = 2 ..
```

When I add 3rd `item[3].cost = 8` it's `Total = 228`. I want add SUM, how to do this? I want total `=12`.

```
addWorkItem() {

    this.current_job.work_items.push(this.current_workitem);
    this.Total = 0;

    for (var i = 0, len = this.current_job.work_items.length; i < len; i++) {
      this.Total += this.current_job.work_items[i].cost;
    }
  this.current_workitem = {};

  }
```

[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm62Z.jpg)

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more of your code but looks like you should call parseFloat on this.current_job.work_items[i].cost when calculating this.Total

Comment: What's not working? What value are you getting for Total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're concatenation the numbers, not adding.

```
addWorkItem() {
  this.current_job.work_items.push(this.current_workitem);
  this.Total = 0;

  for (var i = 0, len = this.current_job.work_items.length; i < len; i++) {
    this.Total += parseFloat(this.current_job.work_items[i].cost);
  }
  this.current_workitem = {};

}
```

Comment: You can also use `type="number"` on your inputs which will convert them to numbers for you and avoid parsing the floats which could return `NaN`.